Disable Edit or Delete for specific record in Filament Laravel
In a model, I have 2 specific columns named 'is_editable' and 'is_deletable' (both are boolen). In filament table, while showing record, I want to disable Edit and/or Delete buttons if  'is_editable' and/or 'is_deletable' set to false. I don't know how to do this. Can anybody help me solving this ?
[Please see table picture here](https://i.sstatic.net/8WSrvCTK.png)
Searched Filament document

You can use hidden() or disabled() methods on your table action, and make them dynamic by injecting $record in the function, like this:
Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make()
   ->disabled(fn($record) => !$record->is_deletable),
Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
   ->disabled(fn($record) => !$record->is_editable),

Same is for hidden:
Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make()
   ->hidden(fn($record) => !$record->is_deletable),
Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
   ->hidden(fn($record) => !$record->is_editable),


Thanks a lot. I just found that in Filament Doc too. Thanks anyway !
